# Editing .htaccess file, multiple domains

Tags: mod-rewrite

Inside the public_html folder their are numerous folders of other domains and a .htaccess file. I need to edit the .htaccess file of a specific domain and not effect the other domains.

Here is how last few entries of the .htaccess file looks like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I want to add this piece of code after RewriteBase but I don't want to screw up the other domains.

```
 RewriteRule ^page/(.*) ads/page/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/ ads/page/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different `.htaccess` files to use using `AccessFileName` in your `VirtualHost` directive:

```
<VirtualHost <ip address>:80 >
    # ...
    AccessFileName .htaccess.some_domain
```

Comment: thanks for this but i'm not an expert in mod rewrite where in my code do i put this?

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: the hosting is Justhost.com, i'm developing a website for my client. We are using Linux.

Comment: Ubuntu? Or some other distro?